# how to grab the link uri in watin testing framework

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, watin

I have to get the url address of the page which i have opened by executing click event.

It works fine as the link was in javascript, it opens a popup, now i want to have the url of this popup 
is there any way to grab the url address..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IE.InternetExplorers collection.

**Example**:  Write out the URLs of all open IE windows

```
foreach (IE currIE in IE.InternetExplorers())
{
    Console.WriteLine("URL: " + currIE.Url);
}
```

If you have an idea on what the URL should be, using a RegEx to find the correct IE instance is hopefully straight forward.  If you have no idea what the URL of the popup is, you could create a list of the URLs before opening the popup, open the popup and compare the new list to the old list to figure out the newly opened URL.

Edit:  Also, once you know the URL, you'll use the AttachTo method to work with the newly found window.  Read more here:  http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html

The above is NUnit and Watin 2.0.

Comment: I forgot that if you know something to identify the popup (eg: regex for the URL or title) you can just use that in the AttachTo as Ashish shows.  If you have no idea how to identify the popup, the collection is the way I know and unfortunately at least as of Watin 2.0 it is only available for the IE object.

Answer (score 0):

If it is alright to open the popup and then get the URL, this mechanism might work for you:

```
Link ReportsLink = browserinstance.Link(Find.ById("ctl00_NavigationTab_tabLink5"));
ReportsLink.Click();
Browser newbrowser = Browser.AttachTo(browserinstance.GetType(), Find.ByTitle("BusinessObjects InfoView"));
string url = newbrowser.Url;
newbrowser.Close();
```

Comment: It works if i have the id of the popup page, but in my case, there is no way for me to know as the tests which i should build should work on all sites(an automated tests)...any how thanks for ur reply, it is useful for in another case.....

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you.

```
string Current_Url= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```